# Flutter package for creating git hook in ./.git/hook folder of Flutter project

Tags: bash, git, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I already have a pre-commit hook in my project, but I want to force all people in my project to use it. For that purpose, I want to write a flutter library for creating files in a flutter project directory(like a husky in js world)! All that I have searched are about widgets libraries and so on!

I know that in js libraries in package.json there is a script object with `install` property. In this property, anybody can write to run a script. Is there an opportunity to do the same thing in dart or flutter?

Comment: This should definitely be re-opened, given that the updates have made this question really relevant

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella can I do it by my own?

Comment: I think you can ask for moderator intervention, but I have never done that before. I've flagged it and asked for a moderator to re-open this one with due context - as it is really relevant.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella you can help to reopen this question. Near with "share", "edit", "delete" buttons there is also the "reopen" button. 

> When a question reaches 5 reopen votes, it is no longer closed, and new answers may be submitted.

Comment: I think I don't have enough reputation :( But good news: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good?cb=1

Comment: Voted to re-open aswell.